# How to test an application when each call changes state of the system?

Tags: api, testing

Testing is simple when you have methods that you can call 100 times and they yield the same results. But how do you test something like an Api, where you have something like this:

```
int CreateUser(username,password); //returns the id of the user, -1 if error
int SubmitOrder(username,password,productName,quantity);//returns the id of the order -1 if error
int CancelOrder(username,password,orderId); //returns -1 if error
```

How would you test that this Api works? How do you create test data? I can not write unit tests fot it, I can not use the same test data, since I can not create a user two times(UserName is unique). When I submit an order I always get different orderIds as responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find some way to "reset" system to well-known initial state, i.e. state with no users nor orders.

Also you need to find some way to observe state in the system.  This way could be actually destructive, i.e. it could modify or even damage state of the system, but though.  In your case, method `CreateUser` could be used as such observer to check whether user already exists, because it is known to return `-1` in such situation.

Here is how one of your test cases could look like:

```
reset (); // Each test case should start with reset
assertNotEquals (-1, CreateUser ("foo", "bar")); // This should work fine
assertEquals (-1, CreateUser ("foo", "zoo")); // Make sure user "foo" does exist
assertNotEquals (-1, SubmitOrder ("foo", "bar", "apple", 1)); // Make sure user can pass authentication
assertEquals (-1, SubmitOrder ("foo", "zoo", "apple", 1)); // Make sure password is actually checked
```

The above test case checks that `CreateUser` actually creates user with given name and passwords, and does not allow creating two users with the same name.

Here is another test case:

```
reset ();
CreateUser ("foo", "bar");
orderID = SubmitOrder ("foo", "bar", "apple", 1); // Submit order
assertNotEquals (-1, CancelOrder (orderID)); // Make sure order was really created
assertEquals (-1, CancelOrder (orderID)); // Make sure order was cancelled
```

And so on.  Of cause it would be better to find more straightforward ways to observe system state, e.g. by querying database directly.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are talking about some OOP language. I think you can solve your problem by Unit Testing and Dependency Injection.
Core concept:

- first you do test of your DataBase class
- when testing API you inject a FakeDataBase class into it (that shares same Interface)

So in testing environment API writes to some other fake database or simply prints queries to a file and you just check if content of this file is what you expected.

Great video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=wEhu57pih5w#!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing